# Summing GridView column values

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a "time duration" column in a grid view, and I wish to sum that particular column in C# and publish the total time taken at a label named Total Time. How can I do this?

Sample code:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dgTestSteps.SelectedColumns.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(dgTestSteps.SelectedColumns.Count.ToString());
    //sum += Convert.ToInt32(dgTestSteps.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
}
lblTotalTime.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: What kind of gridview (Wpf, html, Winforms) what's wrong with the given code etc? You'll need a for each row get column value and sum instead of for each column.

Comment: @Coding: assume winforms because of the `SelectedColumns` property(added tag)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dgTestSteps.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
       sum += Int.Parse(dgTestSteps.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    }
    lblTotalTime.Text = sum.To String();
```

It seems true! Is there any problem with this?

Comment: i tried the above code.. but the result i am getting is "0" , yes it is a windows form, what i feel is this is to be done through databound , but not sure how..can anyone help on this.

Comment: what is the index of your column? is it really 1? 1 means the second column!

Comment: wow there is a big mistake! dgTestSteps.SelectedColumns.Count is not true use dgTestSteps.Rows.Count

Comment: no the  index is 6 as the column is 7th ,i have even tried with dgTestSteps.Rows.Count ,but not working still as it shows some object reference not set error.

Comment: did you used dgTestSteps.Rows[i].Cells[6]?  
And if the last row is blank, try this: for (int i = 0; i < dgTestSteps.Rows.Count-1; i++)

Comment: debug the code, use break point and see what's wrong. or upload your project, then I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by aggregating the column row values in a class variable thusly:

Code behind:

```
        protected void ItemsGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // Get the row variable values
            var rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            var itemId = Convert.ToInt32(rowView["ItemID"]);
            var skuId = Convert.ToInt32(rowView["ItemSkuID"]);
            var quantity = Convert.ToInt32(rowView["Quantity"]);

            // Instantiate instances of the relevant classes
            var item = new Item(itemId);
            var sku = new Sku(skuId);

            var itemPrice = String.Format("{0:n2}", (item.Price + sku.PriceAdj));

            var itemPriceLiteral = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("ItemPrice");
            if (itemPriceLiteral != null)
            {
                itemPriceLiteral.Text = itemPrice;
            }
            var itemExtendedPriceLiteral = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("ItemExtendedPrice");
            if (itemExtendedPriceLiteral != null)
            {
                var extendedPrice = price * quantity;
                itemExtendedPriceLiteral.Text = String.Format("{0:n2}", extendedPrice);

                // Increment the extended price
                _totalExtendedPrice += extendedPrice;
            }
        }
    }
```

> ```
>     // Lots of stuff omitted from this method for clarity
>     public void GetSummary()
>     {
>         // Set the text property of the total literal below the GridView
>         OrderTotal.Text = string.Format((HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(
>             (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("ShopStrings", "UsdPrice"))),
>                                                         _totalExtendedPrice);
>     }
> ```

OrderTotal.Text is localized but you can easily format it without using resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this but you should know that number of columns start with 0 and goes up with 1

```
int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dgTestSteps.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(dgTestSteps.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);

        }
        lblTotalTime.Text = sum.ToString();
```

I tried this and has no problem